# isset code not being executed PHP

Tags: php, isset

I was wondering if my code below is even correct, I've been having numerous errors with this, but am not sure if the problem really exists here. The code is below:

**The user will click 'Exit Group'.**

```
<p class="logout"><a id="exit" name="logout" href="#">Exit Group</a></p>
```

The code that should be execute when 'Exit Group' is clicked is below:

```
if(isset($_GET['logout'])){ 

    //CODE TO BE EXECUTED        
                            }
```

However, the code I am trying to execute when the user clicks 'Exit Group' is not even being executed. **There is nothing wrong with the code within the braces, as numerous people have checked it.** But I was wondering if my problem may lie in the code above? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you click the link, nothing happens because the URL only contains the *fragment identifier `#`*. **Not** even a `GET` request will be issued.

You use this kind of link normally to jump to an element inside the page (e.g. `<a href="#top">Top</a>` to jump to an element with ID `top`). **This is completely handled in the browser**.

And if you only put the fragment identifier there, just nothing will happen. This is very often used if the link should execute some JavaScript and should actually not link to something else.

---

You are testing the  `$_POST` array at the server side. But this array only contains elements, if you initiate a `POST` request by a form. That means you need to create a form with a submit button, e.g.:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="logout" value="Exit Group" />
</form>
```

Here comes the `name` attribute into play, which will be the key in the `$_POST` array. But assigning this on a normal link will have no effect.

---

You could do it also with the link, but with a GET request this way:

```
<a id="exit" href="?logout=1">Exit Group</a>
<!--                 ^-- parameter must be part of the URL, name has no effect    -->
```

and

```
if(isset($_GET['logout'])){    
    //CODE TO BE EXECUTED        
}
```

Note that you have to pass a parameter `logout` it here.

---

It seems you have mixed up `GET` and `POST` requests. If you have a **form**, the `name` s of the **form elements** will be transmitted as parameters to the server. That means given this form:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="foo" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="bar" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" />
</form>
```

if the user clicks on the submit button, the `$_POST` array at the server side will have the keys:

```
$_POST['foo']
$_POST['bar']
$_POST['send']
```

This does not work with links though. A click on a link will create a normal `GET` request, and here, the parameters must be part of the URL, appended after a question mark `?` and separated by an ampersand `&`:

```
<a href="somePage.php?foo=1&bar=1&andMore=0"> Link </a>
```

will result in

```
$_GET['foo']
$_GET['bar']
$_GET['andMore']
```

You probably should read about the [HTTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP).

Comment: SORRY everyone, but I should have mentioned that IT DOES NOT WORK with $_GET either. I tried it before, thus thought $_POST would work, but BOTH OF THEM don't work.

Comment: @newbie-25: Read the first paragraph of my answer. The URL you use is wrong.

Comment: Are you actually passing any URL parameters? Your example doesn't have any, is it a faithful representation of what you're doing?

Answer (score 3):

You're using a regular hyperlink, no form will get posted. you need a submit button of some kind in a form with `method="post"` to do that. regular links just result in GET requests and nothing will ever be posted that way.

edit: added simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'):?>
        <pre><? print_r($_POST)?></pre>
<?endif;?>
        <? // $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] holds the current URL, so we know that ?>
        <? // we'll end up back in this file when the form is submitted.     ?>
        <form method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
            <input type="text" name="textbox" 
                value="<?= isset($_POST['textbox'])?$_POST['textbox']:'Type something' ?>" />
            <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

`a` isnt a form control. it needs to be an `input` or `select` if it's within a form.

For manual linking, do `href="/page?logout"`

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST` will only be filled if you use a form with `method=post`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A POST and a GET are two different things ;)

```
if(isset($_GET['logout']))
```

Answer (score 0):

This `<a id="exit" name="logout" href="#">` should be `<a id="exit" href="?logoff=true#">`.

Then `logoff` will be in the `$_GET` array.